# Automatically refresh JFace element

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, jface

Where can I place my code which would execute each draw cycle?
Example: Let's say you want a timer, or a clock.

Then basically you have your Window, and a label.
The label shows the time, but you need to refresh it.
How do you do it?

Another example: You need to re-check if a server got new data, if it does, refresh your data, and then re-draw your Table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just call the appropriate method to update the control. For a label that would be `setText` for a `TableViewer` you would use `update` or `refresh`.

What you must do is execute the UI updates in the user interface thread. If your code is called from a timer or something like that it may not be in the UI thread. In this case use `Display.asyncExec` to run the update code.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try as soon as I get to my project. (Will accept answer if it works ofc.)